# Is there a comparable SKLearn RFClassifier argument to H2o's 'stopping_rounds'?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, h2o

I'm translating a random forest using h20 and r into a random forest using SciKit Learn's Random Forest Classifier with python.  H2o's randomForest model has an argument 'stopping_rounds'.  Is there a way to do this in python using the SKLearn Random Forest Classifier model? I've looked through the documentation, so I'm afraid I might have to hard code this.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe scikit-learn algorithms have any sort of automatic early stopping mechanism (that's what `stopping_rounds` relates to in H2O algorithms).  You will have to figure out the optimal number of trees manually.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [sklearn random forest classifier docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), early stopping is determined by the `min_impurity_split` (deprecated) and `min_impurity_decrease` arguments. It doesn't seem to have the same functionality as H2O, but it might be what you're looking for.